# How Do You Find The Last Row In A Range That Matches Certain Criteria? (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, find

I have a parts database of over 150 rows of data each with individually unique part numbers with starting letters to indicate their system name (Part-12XX are for bolts or whatnot). Is there a function like textfinder or intuitive way to find the last result of this text range criteria so I could automatically add a part with the next sequential number.

Excel uses find directions or even xlUp to search from bottom up. I looked up the class TextFinder and that did not seem to work.

I'm using Google Apps Script.

```
// Creates  a text finder for the range.
var textFinder = range.createTextFinder('Part-12'); 
// string to be replaced with right() command
```

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Comment: Yeah it absolutely worked. The parts database now automatically finds the last part number and will iterate to the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the row number of the last row when the value which has `Part-12` as the prefix is found in the range of the Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- In this answer, "TextFinder" is used.
- `useRegularExpression()` is used. [The official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#useregularexpressionuseregex) is as follows.

  - > configures the search to interpret the search string as a regular expression; otherwise the search interprets the search string as normal text.
- `findAll()` returns all ranges of the search result as an array. In this case, the last element of the array is the value you want.

#### Sample script:

```
var textFinder = range.createTextFinder('^Part-12').useRegularExpression(true); // In this case, '^Part-12' is used at the regex.
var result = textFinder.findAll(); 
var row = result[result.length - 1].getRow();
Logger.log(row); // This is the last row number.
```

- This script supposes that `range` is declared.

#### References:

- [useRegularExpression()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#useregularexpressionuseregex)
- [findAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findall)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Saif In addition to the answer above, there is also [`findPrevious`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#findPrevious()) to go in reverse.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your support.

Comment: Yeah this absolutely worked hands down. I apologize for not getting back sooner